# Cast from UnsafeRawPointer to CFMutableDictionary failed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem like in this question: [Why AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer stops showing CMSampleBuffers taken from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput's delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700206/why-avsamplebufferdisplaylayer-stops-showing-cmsamplebuffers-taken-from-avcaptur)

And tried advice from this question.

But when I pasted this code:

```
let attachments: CFArray = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sampleBuffer, true)!;

    print(CFArrayGetCount(attachments)) // printing 1

    let dict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachments, 0) as! CFMutableDictionary;

    CFDictionarySetValue(dict,
                         unsafeBitCast(kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self),
                         unsafeBitCast(kCFBooleanTrue, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self));
```

App crashes while casting to CFMutableDictionary.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use CFArray/CFDictionary in Swift. CFArray is toll-free bridged to NSArray, which can be bridged to a Swift Array.

Comment: @MartinR But if he really wanted to do it, he could use your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33310021/341994, right?

Comment: Btw, this looks quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780419/how-to-use-cfdictionarysetvalue-in-swift.

Comment: By the way, @MartinR, I have an example of using your technique with CFDictionary, just to prove it can be done (though no one in his right mind would ever do it): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p829imageIO/ch36p1084imageIO/ViewController.swift

Comment: @matt: `unsafeBitCast(obj, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self)` as in this question should work as well for *objects*. My guess is that the above code crashes because a *boolean* is forcefully converted to a pointer.

Comment: @Евгения: Doesn't this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40780970/1187415 do exactly what you want?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thanks, it solved this problem, but initial problem is still not solved :(

Comment: Here's solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687169/ios-ignoring-enqueuesamplebuffer-because-status-is-failed